# issue with environment...login to sqlplus

Tags: linux, oracle, bash, shell

So i am trying to figure out a simple issue which i know is related to my environment setting....as you can see the oracle database (mcq) is up and running and when i login to the server everything is all set and i can login to the database with SQLPLUS.... But my issue comes in when i switch to bash mode by typing bash(default is csh, when things work)....when i switch to bash and unset everything and set ORACLE_SID, HOME, PATH I get into SQLPLUS but as you can see i get "Connected to an idle instance." message, which means i am not connecting into the database....

the reason why i am unsetting everything and wanting this to work is because of the script i am trying to write.  I do not want to relay on the things that have already been set, as on some servers we have the env set for oracle and on some we dont...so if i get this to work this will work on both env...

```
hostname:oramcq 51> ps -ef|grep pmon
oramcq     3810      1  0 Aug14 ?        00:08:29 ora_pmon_mcq
oramcq   121914 121660  0 13:55 pts/0    00:00:00 grep pmon
hostname:oramcq 52>
hostname:oramcq 52> env | grep ORA
dbms_type=ORA
ORACLE_SID=mcq
ORACLE_BASE=/oracle
ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/mcq/112_64
hostname:oramcq 53>
hostname:oramcq 53> env | grep PATH
PATH=/oracle/mcq/112_64/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sap/mcq/SYS/exe/uc/linuxx86_64:/usr/sap/mcq/SYS/exe/run:/oracle/mcq/11204:.
MODULEPATH=/usr/share/Modules/modulefiles:/etc/modulefiles
RSEC_SSFS_DATAPATH=/usr/sap/mcq/SYS/global/security/rsecssfs/data
RSEC_SSFS_KEYPATH=/usr/sap/mcq/SYS/global/security/rsecssfs/key
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/sap/mcq/SYS/exe/run:/usr/sap/mcq/SYS/exe/uc/linuxx86_64:/oracle/mcq/112_64/lib
hostname:oramcq 54>
hostname:oramcq 54> sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Thu Oct 22 13:56:11 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning and Real Application Testing options

SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning and Real Application Testing options
hostname:oramcq 55>
hostname:oramcq 55>
hostname:oramcq 55> bash
bash-4.1$
bash-4.1$ ORACLE_SID=""
bash-4.1$ ORACLE_HOME=""
bash-4.1$ PATH=/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin
bash-4.1$ export ORACLE_SID=mcq
bash-4.1$ export ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/mcq/11204
bash-4.1$ export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
bash-4.1$ which sqlplus
/oracle/mcq/11204/bin/sqlplus
bash-4.1$
bash-4.1$ env | grep ORA
dbms_type=ORA
ORACLE_SID=mcq
ORACLE_BASE=/oracle
ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/mcq/11204
bash-4.1$
bash-4.1$ env | grep PATH
RSEC_SSFS_DATAPATH=/usr/sap/mcq/SYS/global/security/rsecssfs/data
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/sap/mcq/SYS/exe/run:/usr/sap/mcq/SYS/exe/uc/linuxx86_64:/oracle/mcq/112_64/lib
PATH=/oracle/mcq/11204/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin
MODULEPATH=/usr/share/Modules/modulefiles:/etc/modulefiles
RSEC_SSFS_KEYPATH=/usr/sap/mcq/SYS/global/security/rsecssfs/key
bash-4.1$
bash-4.1$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Thu Oct 22 13:57:20 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL>
```

Comment: Are the two `ORACLE_HOME`'s supposed to be different?

Comment: well that is a good catch...looks like there is a softlink like this 112_64 -> 11204.... shouldn't that still work with 11204...when i set it to 112_64 it works but not with 11204...

Comment: You could try using the `11204` path in csh - if that also fails it's not a bash issue (which I don't think it is).